# Desabilitar botão JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Boa noite pessoal, entendo muito pouco de JavaScript, estou fazendo apenas esse arquivo .js para injetar no meu projeto Java.

Quando o usuário clica várias vezes no botão, o processo é feito várias vezes, e eu precisava de bloquear o botão após o primeiro Click, Alguém poderia dar uma ajuda?? Já tentei de todas as formas, rs

```
 var btn_acao = document.getElementById('rb-acao');
  btn_acao.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var divCount = document.querySelectorAll('.RxpZH');
    if (divCount.length > 0) {
      var list = document.getElementById('rb-list').value;
      var quant = document.getElementById('rb-quant').value;
      if(list == 0){
        alert("Selecione as opções de comentarios!");
      }else if(quant == 0){
        alert("Selecione as opções de quantidade!");
      }else{
        rb_robo(list, quant);
      }
    }else{
      alert('Abra os comentários da publicação para iniciar');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se você pretende somente desabilitar após o primeiro clique, basta colocar o seguinte código:

```
  var btn_acao = document.getElementById('rb-acao'); 
  btn_acao.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.disabled = true
    var divCount = document.querySelectorAll('.RxpZH');
    if (divCount.length > 0) {
      var list = document.getElementById('rb-list').value;
      var quant = document.getElementById('rb-quant').value;
      if(list == 0){
        alert("Selecione as opções de comentarios!");
      }else if(quant == 0){
        alert("Selecione as opções de quantidade!");
      }else{
        rb_robo(list, quant);
      }
    }else{
      alert('Abra os comentários da publicação para iniciar');
    }
  });
```

O *this* nesse caso vai fazer referência a próprio botão e ele irá ficar desabilitado após ser clicado e não irá mais ficar disponível para cliques a não ser que a página tenha sido carregada. É isso que você está procurando?

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu precisava, deu certinho! Muito obrigado.

Answer (score -2):

como vai?

Se entendi bem a sua pergunta, uma solução viável para desabilitar o botão é utilizar o setAttribute(). Sua função é adicionar um novo atributo ou modificar um valor de um atributo já existente. Neste caso, estaríamos adicionando a propriedade 'disabled' (desabilitado) ao botão. É uma solução muito semelhante a que o Mayro passou, só que um tanto mais verbosa.

```
var btn_acao = document.getElementById('rb-acao');
btn_acao.addEventListener('click', () => {

  btn_acao.setAttribute('disabled', ''); // adicionado a propriedade 'disabled'

  var divCount = document.querySelectorAll('.RxpZH');
  if (divCount.length > 0) {
    var list = document.getElementById('rb-list').value;
    var quant = document.getElementById('rb-quant').value;
    if (list == 0) {
      alert("Selecione as opções de comentarios!");
    } else if (quant == 0) {
      alert("Selecione as opções de quantidade!");
    } else {
      rb_robo(list, quant);
    }
  } else {
    alert('Abra os comentários da publicação para iniciar');
  }
});
```